# Lista duplamente encadeada - Java

Tags: java, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando criar (estou aprendendo) uma lista duplamente encadeada baseada em um exercício, em que a lista será um trem com vagões. O exercício pede que se crie uma classe "vagão", onde se encontram as variáveis "nome do vagão", "próximo vagão" e "vagão anterior", e que se crie outra classe "trem", onde se encontram as variáveis "head" e "tail", e os métodos para adicionar vagões, para imprimir os vagões e outro para mudar a ordem das locomotivas. Meu problema está em como o exercício pede para se criar o método para adicionar vagões. Ele passa como parâmetro uma variável que não foi declarada, tendo como tipo de dado a classe "vagão", então eu não estou conseguindo criar esse método. Vou mostrar o que eu fiz no código abaixo. Será que alguém teria como me dar uma dica quanto a isso? Simplesmente, não estou conseguindo entender como vou usar o parâmetro "vagaoCriar" no método.

Além disso, o exercício pede que se criem dois trens, então duas listas, e usando o método para trocar as locomotivas, que se troque a locomotiva do primeiro trem com a do segundo. Gostaria de saber, isso é realmente possível de se realizar usando uma lista duplamente encadeada (ou no caso, duas)? Porque já pesquisei bastante e não vi nada sobre isso. Vi que é possível mudar a ordem dos elementos de uma lista, mas trocar os elementos entre duas listas, não tenho certeza.

```java
public class Vagao {
    String nomeDoVagao;
    Wagon vagaoAnterior;
    Wagon vagaoPosterior;

    public Vagao (String nomeDoVagao){
        this.nomeDoVagao = nomeDoVagao;
        vagaoAnterior = null;
        vagaoPosterior = null;
    }
}

public class Trem {
    Vagao head, tail = null;

    //Não estou sabendo criar aqui
    public void adicionarVagao (Vagao vagaoCriar){
        Vagao novo_Vagao = new Vagao (vagaoCriar.nomeDoVagão);

        if (head == null){
            head = tail = novo_Vagao;
            head.vagaoAnterior = null;
            tail.vagaoPosterior = null;
        } else {
            tail.vagaoPosterior = novo_Vagao;
            novo_Vagao.vagaoAnterior = tail;
            tail = novo_Vagao;
            tail.vagaoPosterior = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou dar exemplos de como pode fazer essa lista

Duplamente encadeada não-circular:

```
public class Trem {
   private Vagao head = null;
   private Vagao tail = null;

   public boolean tremVazio(){
      if (head == null && tail == null)
         return true;
      else
         return false;
   }

   public void adicionarInicio(Vagao novo) {

      if(tremVazio()) {
         head = novo;
         tail = novo;
      }
      else {
         novo.vagaoPosterior = head;
         head = novo;
         novo.vagaoPosterior.vagaoAnterior = head;
      }
   }

   public void adicionarFinal(Vagao novo) {

      if(tremVazio()) {
         head = novo;
         tail = novo;
      }
      else {
         novo.vagaoAnterior = tail;
         tail = novo;
         novo.vagaoAnterior.vagaoPosterior = tail;
      }
   }
    
    
   public void imprimir() {
       Vagao aux = head;
       
       while(aux != null) {
           System.out.println("Vagao: " + aux.nomeDoVagao);
           if(aux.vagaoAnterior != null)
               System.out.println("Anterior: " + aux.vagaoAnterior.nomeDoVagao);
           if(aux.vagaoPosterior != null)
               System.out.println("Posterior: " + aux.vagaoPosterior.nomeDoVagao);
           System.out.println("------------------------------------");
           aux = aux.vagaoPosterior;
       }
       
   }
}
```

Duplamente encadeada circular:

```
public class Trem {
   private Vagao head = null;
   private Vagao tail = null;

   public boolean tremVazio(){
     if (head == null && tail == null)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
   }

   public void adicionarInicio(Vagao novo){

     if(tremVazio()){
        head = novo;
        tail = novo;
     }

     novo.vagaoPosterior = head;
     novo.vagaoAnterior = tail;
     head = novo;
     novo.vagaoPosterior.vagaoAnterior = novo;
     tail.vagaoPosterior = novo;
   }

   public void adicionarFinal(Vagao novo){

     if(tremVazio()){
        head = novo;
        tail = novo;
     }

     novo.vagaoPosterior = head;
     novo.vagaoAnterior = tail;
     tail = novo;
     novo.vagaoPosterior.vagaoAnterior = novo;
     novo.vagaoAnterior.vagaoPosterior = novo;
   }
    
    
   public void imprimir() {
       Vagao aux = head;
       
       do {
           System.out.println("Vagao: " + aux.nomeDoVagao);
           if(aux.vagaoAnterior != null)
               System.out.println("Anterior: " + aux.vagaoAnterior.nomeDoVagao);
           if(aux.vagaoPosterior != null)
               System.out.println("Posterior: " + aux.vagaoPosterior.nomeDoVagao);
           System.out.println("------------------------------------");
           aux = aux.vagaoPosterior;
       }while(aux != head);
       
   }
}
```

Fiz de cabeça durante a aula, então posso ter varado algo aí. To deixando livre pra edição o código. É interessante você também fazer métodos de busca, remoção, inserção no meio, etc.

Sobre a troca de locomotiva, não me parece fazer sentido, sendo o trem sendo feito apenas de vagões. Se souber falar mais sobre essa questão, comenta aqui ou manda lá no [meu twitter](https://twitter.com/lageoctavio).